# SVPWM lookup table

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I tried to control the three-phase BLDC motor in the SVPWM method. I use the lookup table for SVPWM. The below one is from saddle waveform (3rd harmonic rejection) which contains 1/3rd period to zero (reduce switching loss). I can run the motor the problem I face with starting the motor produce a noise at low speed. when I drive the motor at full speed the noise is getting reduced. can anyone correct me or any other lookup table.

```cpp
static unsigned char SinusoidalWaveTable[384]={      127,131,135,138,142,145,149,152,155,159,162,165,168,171,174,177,180,183,186,189,192,194,197,200,      202,205,207,210, 212,214,217,219,221,223,225,227,229,231,232,234,236,237,239,240,242,243,244,245,      247,248,249,250,250,251,252,253,253,254,254,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,254,254,      253,253,252,252,251,250,249,248,247,246,245,244,242,241,240,238,237,235,233,232,230,228,226,224,      222,222,225,226,228,230,232,234,235,237,238,240,241,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,252,      253,254,254,254,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,254,254,254,253,252,252,251,250,249,248,       247,246,245,244,243,241,240,238,237,235,234,232,230,228,227,225,223,220,218,216,214,212,209,207,      204,202,199,197,194,191,188,185,183,180,177,174,171,167,164,161,158,154,151,148,144,141,137,134,      130,127,123,119,116,112,108,104,101, 97, 93, 89, 85, 81, 77, 73, 69, 65, 61, 57, 53, 49, 45, 41,       36, 32, 28, 24, 20, 16, 12,  7,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,         0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,         0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  6, 10, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31,       35, 39, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 68, 72, 76, 80, 84, 88, 92, 96, 99,103,107,111,115,118,121,124  }
```

cahnnel 1(yellow) - Phase waveform
channel 2(greeen) - phase current
[image]